# Query to find all ingredients required to make an item by id

Tags: mysql

I'm having a hard time trying to query "all ingredients and counts required to make this item".
The problem is, an item is sometimes composed of a few different recipes, for example:

To make item_id 5 requires:

```
|  item_id  |  count  |
|     10    |   1     |
|     11    |   1     |
```

but item_id 10 requires

```
|  item_id  |  count  |
|     23    |   5     |
|     24    |   5     |
```

and for item_id 11 it requires

```
|  item_id  |  count  |
|     32    |   3     |
|     32    |   3     |
```

And it is also possible for, say item_id 32, to be a composite of another recipe.

How can I query these tables to get back all ingredients and counts required to produce item_id 5?

mysql table layouts below:

```
item (table)
+---------------------+
| item_id             |
| name                |
+---------------------+

recipe (table)
+-------------------+
| Field             |
+-------------------+
| recipe_id         |
| output_item_count |
| output_item_id    |
+-------------------+

recipeingredient (table)
+---------------------+
| recipeingredient_id |
| itemcount           |
| item_id             |
| recipe_id           |
+---------------------+
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can't do this in a single MySQL query because MySQL doesn't support recursive queries.  Your own option would be to do separate queries in a recursive subroutine.

Comment: "recursive queries" - Thank you, I couldn't put a word to what I needed.  Since this is kind of crucial, I will switch to PostgreSQL and re-ask the question when ready.